# Unable to see mssql docker image after successfully pulling from registry

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu-22.04

I pulled the mssql docker image using `sudo docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`

This returned that the image was successfully pulled.

But when I run `docker images` I can't see it listed

I tried viewing the images from the docker client gui and it still doesn't show up, I created a container with the image which worked, but also I'm unable to view the container on docker client gui or the command line with `docker ps`

Comment: Some things aren't meant to be run with `sudo`. Have you tried without `sudo`?

Comment: Using `sudo` with docker is not recommended. Instead, add yourself to the docker group and restart the docker service: `sudo usermod -aG docker "$(whoami)" ; sudo service docker start`

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning and @DannyB, the problem was indeed `sudo` thanks.